# Android onclicklistener at different layouts, i keep failing

Tags: java, android, layout, onclicklistener

I have searched thorougly on the internet for an answer, and tried different setups, but i just cant get this to work. The thing is, i am not completely sure what to search for, and how to formulate it correctly, anyways, my problem is:

My setup is: 
Developing for android 2.1 in eclipse.

I want to add an onclicklistener to different layouts.
I have 2 different layouts, main.xml, and ChiOverview.xml.
I have to buttons (imagebutton1 and imagebutton2) in my main.xml file, and 4 buttons (one of them being ChIdentifierbutton). When ever the onclicklistener is made for the ChIdentifierbutton, which is at a different layout, my app crashes.

here is the source code for my ChIdentifierActivity,java:

```
    package feldballe.FPConsult;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;

    public class ChIdentifierActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        ImageButton imageButton;
        ImageButton imageButton2;
        ImageButton imageButton3;
        Preview preview;
        CameraDemo camerademo;
        SeekBar ChIdentifierBar;
        ImageView imageViewChi;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            addListenerOnButton();
        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {          
            imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   setContentView(R.layout.chioverview);
                }
            });

            imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   setContentView(R.layout.yuwrong);
                }
            });

            imageButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ChIdentifierButton);
            imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View chioverview) {
                   setContentView(R.layout.yuwrong);
                }
            });     
    }
}
```

My main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="@string/pushChi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/mainchi" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/realchi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/weucom"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

my chioverview.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/ChiFunfactsButton"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:text="@string/ChiFunfacts" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/ChiCalButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ChiFunfactsButton"
        android:text="@string/ChiCalendar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ChIdentifierButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ChiCalButton"
        android:text="@string/ChIdentifier2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ChiPhotosButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ChiFunfactsButton"
        android:text="@string/ChiPhotos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ChIdentifierButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:text="@string/WhereYuWannaGo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my logcat:

```
06-29 04:43:23.566: I/dalvikvm(1043): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-29 04:43:23.837: I/dalvikvm(1043): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-29 04:43:24.096: I/dalvikvm(1043): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-29 04:43:24.157: I/dalvikvm(1043): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-29 04:43:24.209: D/gralloc_goldfish(1043): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-29 04:43:32.436: D/AndroidRuntime(1043): Shutting down VM
06-29 04:43:32.436: W/dalvikvm(1043): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at feldballe.FPConsult.ChIdentifierActivity$1.onClick(ChIdentifierActivity.java:50)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-29 04:43:32.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 04:43:33.056: I/dalvikvm(1043): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-29 04:43:33.076: I/dalvikvm(1043): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS...

While i was tracing your error log..i found this

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to` `android.widget.ImageButton`

You have **used Button in your layout**, and you are **casting it to ImageButton in the class**.

Either use ImageButton in your layout, or use Button in your class to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Check out my edited code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class ChIdentifierActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ImageButton imageButton;
ImageButton imageButton2;
ImageButton imageButton3;


Preview preview;
CameraDemo camerademo;

SeekBar ChIdentifierBar;
ImageView imageViewChi;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();
}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           setContentView(R.layout.chioverview);
           imageButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ChIdentifierButton);
           imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View chioverview) {
              setContentView(R.layout.yuwrong);

           }

           }); 
        }

       });

    imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           setContentView(R.layout.yuwrong);

        }

    });

}
}
```

Hope this may help you..

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but it still does not work.. :(

Comment: You are setting another screen on click of a button in your Activity.If you do so you are not allowed to return back to previous screen.Generally it is done using creating Intent and calling Another Activity class.

Comment: Ill try rewriting to get another class to do it.. I guess it would be smartes to just run another activityclass, and run the "setContentView" within that class, and making the onclicklistener there as well.. Ill let you know how it goes, thank you so much.

Comment: Check your xml files main.xml and chioverview.xml.Check whether you declared the buttons As `ImageButton` and not as `Buttons`

Comment: Thanks, i tried making it a button in both xml and activity, now i got the error:
06-29 06:00:51.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{feldballe.FPConsult/feldballe.FPConsult.ChIdentifierActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Could that be due to me not using intent?

Answer (score 0):

> ImageButton imageButton;
>
> ImageButton imageButton2;
>
> ImageButton imageButton3;

acc to your log, you are probably casting a Button to an ImageButton.
can you paste the code for main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem

your findViewById() function looks for an ImageButton with an id "R.id.ChIdentifierButton"

```
ImageButton imageButton3;    
imageButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ChIdentifierButton);
        imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View chioverview) {
               setContentView(R.layout.yuwrong);
            }
        });
```

while you assigned "R.id.ChIdentifierButton" to a Button in your xml

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/ChIdentifierButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ChiCalButton"
    android:text="@string/ChIdentifier2" />
```

hence, the class-cast exception :-)